# Intel 7260 Wireless Network Adapter with Debian kernel version 3.2.0-4-amd64

Tags: debian, wifi, intel

I'm using Debian 3.2.65 with kernel version 3.2.0-4-amd64 and I'm having issues getting the Intel 7260 card working (http://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-7260-bluetooth.html), could anyone give some insight into why this isn't working?

This is all the relevant information that I can think of;

```
sudo lspci | grep Network
```

gives;

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 08b1 (rev c3)
```

What I think might be important from lshw

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
            description: Network controller
            product: Intel Corporation
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            version: c3
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:d0600000-d0601fff
```

uname -a gives (just checking I've not put anything wrong in the description or something);

Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

iwconfig gives;

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

the 7260 driver is in /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode (installed via apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [wifi not working, have I installed the correct drivers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197112/wifi-driver-not-working); your wifi adapter needs kernel 3.10 or later. You can install 3.16 from the [Debian backports](http://backports.debian.org/), or wait for the release of Debian 8 in just a few days (April 25).