# wifi not working, have I installed the correct drivers?

Tags: wifi

I have a laptop with wifi not working: I can detect hardware with `lshw` and `lspci`, but that is it. `network-manager` is not showing it.

`lshw -numeric -C network`
reports

```
*-network UNCLAMED
description: Network contriller
product: Intel corporation [8086:8B4]
vendor: Intel corporation [8086]
physical id:0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 93
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory: c1000000-c1001fff
```

From here http://linux-wless.passys.nl/query_chipset.php?chipset=Intel I see that it needs driver `iwlwifi`. I have installed `firmware-iwlwifi`.

`lspci` shows

```
…
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9cb1
…
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 08b4 (rev 93)
```

(apology for the truncation, it is on another device, with no network)

If I do `rfkill list all`
I get

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    SoftBlocked: no
    HardBlocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    SoftBlocked: no
    HardBlocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    SoftBlocked: no
    HardBlocked: no
```

If I press the airplane button then id 1 goes to `SoftBlocked: yes`, then back to `no`, on next press.

---

Output of `uname -srmo`

`Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Distro: `Debian wheezy (7)`

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What do `lspci` and `ip addr show`? Could you add an IP address to the wireless interface and ping it?

Comment: IP address is at osi-layer 3, I dream of layer 3. This is I think layer 1 hardware. We can see the hardware exists, but not get it to work.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand your response but to know if the hardware works or not, I suppose you've checked the logs and saw there is no association with the nearest access point, right? Hard to guess without a log trace. From your `lspci` output I can see it doesn't have the device friendly name in its database, which means, either you haven't updated it for a long time or the hardware is too recent. Check `iwlfiwi` [support](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm) for your wireless adapter could just be not yet supported.

Comment: @Nasha I followed your supprt link to intels site, and found the driver (7260 ac), it says there I need a newer kernel, at least 3.10, so I found that there is a 3.16 in wheezy-backports. I installed it, and rebooted, it now works. No need to manually download firmware as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by upgrading the kernel to `3.16`, it is in wheezy-backports, it is also in jessie, expected to be released on 25 Apr 2015 (latter this month).

*Thanks to @Nasha 's comment, I followed your support link to intel's site, and found the driver (7260 ac), it says there, that I need a newer kernel, at least `3.10`, so I found that there is a `3.16` in wheezy-backports. I installed it, and rebooted, it now works. No need to manually download firmware as well.*